# Spring MVC web.xml's DispatcherServlet instances per url-mapping

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Spring MVC web.xml has DispatcherServlet which acts as FrontController, I am a bit confused with concept of Servlet in spring, as I know there is only one instance of Servlet in a web container and multiple threads operate on service() method but in case of Spring is there is only one instance of DispatcherServlet created per url-mapping or we have multiple instances of DispatacherServlet.

Ex:
Mapping to jsp calls:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config-jsp.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Mapping to HTML calls:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config-html.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Simply putting how many instances of DispatcherServlet are created on above example for mapping html and jsp calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just like any normal Java Servlets, you can define two instances of same servlet class by assigning different Servlet names for each `<servlet>` declaration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jspDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>htmlDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
</servlet>
```

It is also clearly pointed out in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) that you can safely define multiple instances of `DispatcherServlet` within one web application.

> A web application can define any number of `DispatcherServlets`. Each
>   servlet will operate in its own namespace, loading its own application
>   context with mappings, handlers, etc. Only the root application
>   context as loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`, if any, will be shared.

So as long as you map the two Servlets to two different URL patterns, you are all good.

Comment: When does the Spring WebApplicationContext will be created in these scenarios for each DispatcherServlet, who is responsible for creating the WebApplicationContext object for each DispatcherServet

Comment: Spring associates one `WebApplicationContext` per each `DispatcherServlet` created inside the container.

Comment: You didn't get my question, I am asking when an application starts up, web.xml will be read to load servlets, so our DispatcherServlet will be loaded but Spring is still not in picture , now my query is :IS DispatcherServlet instantiating the WebApplicationContext or it is taken care by server. Hope I make sense now.

Comment: Actually the answer is DispatcherServlet init() method is initialising the WebApplicationContext. Thanks anyways.Cheers

Comment: Yes that is right. When the container loads the `DispatcherServlet`, the `WebApplicationContext` is created (during the execution of the `init()` method).